# Django: return distinct set of many to many relationship belonging to a particular model

Tags: python, django, database

I want a query that returns all the distinct tags belonging to all the entries in Model A. I suspect it's possible with clever query and a bit of filtering, but I can't work it out. I want to minimise database hits.

Models:

```
class Tag(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length = 50,)
    category = models.CharField(max_length = 50, blank=True)

class A(models.Model):
    ...
    tags = models.ManyToManyField(Tag, blank=True)

class B(models.Model):
    ...
    tags = models.ManyToManyField(Tag, blank=True)
```

My solution in the meantime is:

```
tags = list()

for a in A.objects.all():
     for t in a.tags.all():
         if t not in tags:
             tags.append(t)
```

Is there an elegant solution to achieve the above functionality?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Tag.objects.filter(a__isnull=False).distinct()` ought to do it.

It's not ultimately relevant here, because the database will be able to do it for you (I may have misremembered a bit of syntax above but if so it'll be correctable, this is definitely doable in a single query) but if you were in a situation where you were operating on data that's *not* in a database, you'd be much better off using `tags = set()` rather than `tags = list()` - it'll manage uniqueness for you, and much more efficiently than repeatedly testing for membership in a list. EG:

```
tags = set()
for a in some_iterable:
    for t in a.some_function():
        tags.add(t)
```

That can be condensed into a nested generator expression, which would be somewhat faster - but the use of `set` rather than `list` is the key change, so I kept it similar to your original attempt. The nested generator expression would look something like:

```
tags = set(t for a in some_iterable for t in a.some_function())
```

And if you're not planning to further modify `tags`, `frozenset(t for a in ...)` instead is a good habit to build.

Comment: I assume you mean: `Tag.objects.all().filter(a__isnull=False).distinct()` ?

Comment: Yup, thanks. I'll correct. Well, the `all()` isn't needed - `Tag.objects.filter(...).distinct()`

Comment: Thank you for your speedy answer Peter DeGlopper. I've got a lot to learn. If anyone has any good resources on django model manipulation and filtering, a link to it would be much appreciated.

Comment: This particular topic is covered decently in the section of the docs covering "Lookups that span relationships" - https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/db/queries/#lookups-that-span-relationships